# Where can I get SCAYT documentation, or algorithm?

Tags: ckeditor

I am using CK editor, now I want to understand SCAYT, but the scayt plug-in provided by SPellchecker.net is minified, and not well documented but I need to understand some of the features.

Can anyone provide me with such type of document or any algorithm related to this.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

- Download CKEditor 3.0.2 from http://ckeditor.com/download.
- Decompress the file, and look for the directory `_source/plugins/scayt`, which will contain a file named `plugin.js`.
- That file is not minified.

Comment: while scate plugin is enabled, it loads many files and those are minified. That is the problem.